# Why do I get this error? Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Employees'

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT Employees.employee_id AS `Employees__employee_id`, 
    Employees.designation_id AS `Employees__designation_id`, 
    Employees.first_name AS `Employees__first_name`, 
    Employees.last_name AS `Employees__last_name`, 
    Employees.address AS `Employees__address`, 
    Employees.contact_no AS `Employees__contact_no`, 
    Employees.joining_date AS `Employees__joining_date`, 
    Employees.username AS `Employees__username`, 
    Employees.password AS `Employees__password`, 
    Employees.basic_pay AS `Employees__basic_pay`, 
    Employees.create_date AS `Employees__create_date`, 
    Employees.status AS `Employees__status`, 
    Designations.designation_id AS `Designations__designation_id`, 
    Designations.designation_name AS `Designations__designation_name`, 
    Designations.description AS `Designations__description` 
FROM employees Employees 
INNER JOIN employees Employees 
    ON Employees.employee_id = (Employees.employee_id) 
INNER JOIN designations Designations 
    ON Designations.designation_id = (Employees.designation_id) 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The ERROR I get is:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not
>   unique table/alias: 'Employees'!

Can you help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same alias (`Employees`) for more than one table in your query. Here, you're using it in both the `from` and the `join` clauses. Just use a different alias in one of them and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

In your `FROM` clause you're setting a table alias `Employees` which is OK as long as your MySQL runs case sensitive (like on Linux or Unix) or may fail if you run it on Windows, but later in your `INNER JOIN` clause you join the table with the same alias. This is a duplicate alias. SQL does not permit duplicate aliases cause otherwise it will not know expression from what table should it evaluate when you call `Employees.designation_id` for example.

Table alias for the main table and for the joined table must be different no matter if you join the same table or not.

Update: Maybe you don't need to join the same table once more. Drop the `inner join employees` part:

```
SELECT Employees.employee_id AS `Employees__employee_id`, 
    Employees.designation_id AS `Employees__designation_id`, 
    Employees.first_name AS `Employees__first_name`, 
    Employees.last_name AS `Employees__last_name`, 
    Employees.address AS `Employees__address`, 
    Employees.contact_no AS `Employees__contact_no`, 
    Employees.joining_date AS `Employees__joining_date`, 
    Employees.username AS `Employees__username`, 
    Employees.password AS `Employees__password`, 
    Employees.basic_pay AS `Employees__basic_pay`, 
    Employees.create_date AS `Employees__create_date`, 
    Employees.status AS `Employees__status`, 
    Designations.designation_id AS `Designations__designation_id`, 
    Designations.designation_name AS `Designations__designation_name`, 
    Designations.description AS `Designations__description` 
FROM employees Employees 

INNER JOIN designations Designations 
    ON Designations.designation_id = (Employees.designation_id) 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks bro .. but how can I edit the query in case of cakephp?!